# How can I compare .text and .data segments of a .dll against the same ones in a different .dll?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, dll, enums, visual-studio-macros

I have a 20+ yo `.dll`, written in C that none of my colleagues want to touch.  With good reason, it uses macros, macro constants and casting EVERYWHERE, making the symbol table quite lean.

Unfortunately, I have to sometimes debug this code and it drives me crazy that it doesn't use something as simple as `enum`s which would put symbols in the `.pdb` file to make debugging just that little bit easier.

I would love to convert some of the `#define`s to `enum`s, even if I don't change the variable types as yet, but there is a genuine fear that it will cause possible issues in terms of performance if it were to change the code generated.

I need to show definitively, that no compiled code changes will occur, but it would seem that the `.dll` is actually changing significantly in a 64 bit build.  I looked at one of the function's disassembly code and it appears to be unaffected, but I need to show what is and is not changing in the binary to alleviate the fears of my colleagues as well as some of my own trepidation, plus the bewilderment as to why any changes would propagate to the `.dll` at all, though the `.dll`s are of the same size.

Does anyone have any idea how I could do this?  I've tried to use `dumpbin`, but I'm not that familiar with it and am getting some mixed results, prolly because I'm not understanding the output as much as I like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I did this was as follows:

1. Turn on **/FAs** switch for project.
2. Compile that project.
3. Move the object file directory (*Release* => *Release-without-enums*)
4. Change *#defines* to *enums*
5. Compile that project again.
6. Move the object file directory (*Release* => *Release-with-enums*)
7. From a bash command line. Use the command from the parent of the Release directory:

```bash
for a in Release-without-enum/*.asm; do
    git diff --no-index --word-diff --color -U10000 $a "Release-with-enum/$(basename $a)";
done | less -R
```

The `-U10000` is just so that I can see the entire file of each file.  Remove it if you just want to see the changes.

This will list all of the modifications in the generated assembly code.

The changes found were as follows:

1. Symbol addresses were moved about for apparently no reason
2. *Referencing **__FILE__** seems to result in not getting a full path when using enums. Why this would translate to removing the full path when using enums is a mystery as the compiler flags have not changed.*
3. *Some symbols were renamed for apparently no reason.*

## *Edit*

*2 and 3 seem to be caused by a corrupted `.pdb` error.  This might be due to the files being used in multiple projects in the same solution.  Rebuilding the entire solution fixed those 2 problems.*